# Elastic search failed to run after X-pack plugin enabled in Windows 10 64 bit machine?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-x-pack

I'm trying ELK 6.0.0 on Windows but I have a problem with X-Pack and Machine Learning.
I have installed the X-Pack plugin in command prompt.it successfully installed the plugin.

```
elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```

When I start Elasticsearch, I have an exception :

```
C:\\Users\ELK\6.0.0\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch
[2018-05-30T15:26:11,578][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2018-05-30T15:26:11,703][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Icp0LXw] using [1] data paths, mounts [[OSDISK (C:)]], net usable_space [107.8gb], net total_space [149.9gb], types [NTFS]
[2018-05-30T15:26:11,703][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [Icp0LXw] heap size [998.4mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [unknown]
[2018-05-30T15:26:12,054][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [Icp0LXw] derived from node ID [Icp0LXwiRfG4Rq-1z9cvDA]; set [node.name] to override
[2018-05-30T15:26:12,054][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[6.0.0], pid[9800], build[8f0685b/2017-11-10T18:41:22.859Z], OS[Windows 10/10.0/x86], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM/1.8.0_144/25.144-b01]
[2018-05-30T15:26:12,054][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\Users\41809\ELK\6.0.0\elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\41809\ELK\6.0.0\elasticsearch\config]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,546][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,546][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [parent-join]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [percolator]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [reindex]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [repository-url]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded module [tribe]
[2018-05-30T15:26:13,561][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [Icp0LXw] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2018-05-30T15:26:15,589][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.XPackPlugin
[2018-05-30T15:26:17,034][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
```

**Platform Configuration:
Windows 10 Enterprise 64 Bit.**

Please help to fix the issue.
Thanks Advance.

Comment: Are you sure that your system version is 64bit? What's your X-Pack version?

Comment: Yes, 64 bit only. x-Pack version - 6.0.0

Comment: It's weird because log says that you have 32 bit `OS[Windows 10/10.0/x86]`. Please type in in your console `wmic os get osarchitecture` and tell us what it returns.